# Kill all threads if condition is met

Tags: python, multithreading

I am currently using python concurrent.futures to add threading to my function.

I want to kill all threads and continue down the program (or exit out if there is nothing else to do) if 1 thread of the pool matches a condition. All other threads in the pool should stop (either abruptly or gracefully)

```
import concurrent.futures
import random


def randomizer(number):
    print("Randomized: "+str(number+random.randrange(0,10)))

    if some_case:
        allthreads.kill()   # This is obviously non working code

if __name__ == '__main__':

    numbers=[5,4,3,2,1,0]

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(randomizer, numbers)
```

Comment: Well, killing threads is not directly possible in python.

Comment: @BlackThunder Is there any way to stop further threads from running? Even waiting for the current threads running to stop would work

Comment: @BlackThunder What i'm not managing to understand in that code is how threading handles the event. After the event being set, how is it stopping continuation?

Comment: That's started in the answer there: "The thread should check the stop flag at regular intervals." In other words, you need to write your threads a certain way.